# Google map marker wont get replaced when getting updated

Tags: angular, google-maps-markers, markers

I've been trying various code blocks here and on the Google Maps API documentation but still have not been able to figure out how to hide the previous markers when the map is re-initialized.

This is the current code im using. Here im fetching the `Marker` objects from an observable service from 'Firestore'. Once a Geopoint is updated for a User, this service will fetch the updated markers and the marker on the map is set to be updated as well. Now the issue is once the map is initialized once the markers are updated, the previous position's markers are not removed from the map.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-map",
  templateUrl: "./map.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./map.component.css"]
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.spinner.show();
 }

 @ViewChild("mapContainer", { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;

 defaultCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127753,-74.0059728);
 mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = {
   center: this.defaultCenter,
   zoom: 8
 };
 private map: any = google.maps.Map;
 markers = [];
 interpreters = [];
 markersMap: Map<String, google.maps.Marker> = new Map();
 focusedInterpreter: any;

 constructor(private interpreterService : InterpreterService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {

   let isRefresh = false;
   this.interpreterService.getInterpreterMarkers().subscribe(userMarkers => {
       this.interpreters = userMarkers;
       userMarkers.forEach(markerInfo => {  
          let marker = this.createGoogleMarker(markerInfo);  
          isRefresh = this.resolveMarker(marker);
       });
       this.updateMarkers();
    });
  }

  createGoogleMarker(markerInfo : Marker): any {
    let marker = { 
        title: markerInfo.name,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(markerInfo.latitude), Number(markerInfo.longitute), false),
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: markerInfo.type == 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
        id: markerInfo.id
   }
    return marker;
  }

  resolveMarker(marker): boolean {
    if (this.markersMap.has(marker.id)) {
        this.markersMap.delete(marker.id);
        this.markersMap.set(marker.id, marker);
        return true;
    } else { 
        this.markersMap.set(marker.id, marker);
        return true;
    }
 }

  updateMarkers(): void { 
      this.markers.splice(0,this.markers.length);
      this.markersMap.forEach((value: any, key: String) => {
      this.markers.push(value);
    });
   this.mapInitializer();
  }

  mapInitializer(): void {
    if (this.focusedInterpreter == null) {
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmap.nativeElement, this.mapOptions);
      this.loadAllMarkers();
    } else {
      let position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.focusedInterpreter.latitude, this.focusedInterpreter.longitute);
      this.map.setCenter(position);
      this.loadAllMarkers();
    }
  }

  loadAllMarkers(): void { 
    this.clearOverlays();
    this.markers.forEach(markerInfo => {
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        ...markerInfo
      });
      const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: marker.getTitle() + " (" + markerInfo.id + ")"
     });

     marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
       infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
     });
     marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
       infoWindow.close();
     });
     marker.setMap(this.map);
   });
   this.spinner.hide();
 }

  clearOverlays() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++ ) {
        console.log(this.markers[i]);
        this.markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }


  focusOnLocation(event): void {
   let position = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latitude, event.longitute);
    this.map.setCenter(position);
    this.focusedInterpreter = event;
  }
}
```

Now as some of the answers had suggested, im using `clearOverlays()` function to loop the markers and set the map to null. But getting `ERROR TypeError: this.markers[i].setMap is not a function`.

Any idea idea what going wrong here.

Heres an image of the issue.

[image: map-issue]

Comment: I think the problem might be because you're mutating `markers` array in `updateMarkers`

Comment: @vitaliykotov oh i didnt realize that. any way to avoid it?

Comment: Try to assign new array instance like `this.markers = [...this.markersMap.values()]`

Comment: @vitaliykotov `this.markers.splice(0,this.markers.length);`
   `this.markers = [...this.markersMap.values()];` 
this didnt work either

Comment: it just was a guess and it's hard find a problem without live(stackblitz f.e.) example